# How to use robotlegs and signals without flex ie. pure as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, signals, robotlegs

I'm try to put together a bare bones robotlegs-signals project but all the samples I've seen are flex ie

Index.mxml

```
 <context:SignalCafeContext contextView="{this}"/>
```

SignalCafeContext.as

```
public class SignalCafeContext extends SignalContext
  {
    override public function startup():void
    {  
        injector.mapSingleton.... etc etc
    }
}
```

Is this possible to replace the mxml with another .as file - normally I would pass from the main class

```
context = new MyContext(this); // where this is DisplayObjectContainer
```

however super() takes no parameters in SignalContext so I might be missing something.

More Info:

libs:

as3-signals-v0.5.swc

robotlegs-framework-v1.03.swc

signals-extensions-SignalsCommandMap.swc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying would work in the current RobotLegs v.1 release (v.1.5.2). Context and its subclass SignalContext take optional params. The first param is your context view:

```
contextView:DisplayObjectContainer = null
```

Here's the [`SignalContext`](https://github.com/joelhooks/signals-extensions-CommandSignal/blob/master/src/org/robotlegs/mvcs/SignalContext.as) class extending `Context`.
Note, Context in Robotlegs 2 does not take parameters ([source](https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-framework/blob/version2/src/robotlegs/bender/framework/impl/Context.as)).

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you need to start with a actionscript project instead of a flex project in FlashBuilder first.

Yes, your right, you just [extend the Context class](https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-demos-Bundle/blob/master/HelloFlash/src/org/robotlegs/demos/helloflash/HelloFlashContext.as), as you can see in the basic [HelloFlash robotlegs demo](https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-demos-Bundle/tree/master/HelloFlash)

Comment: I'm afraid this goes a fair way beyond the hello world robotlegs sample. I've built several apps using event dispatcher and robotlegs - the difference is SignalContext not Context. SignalContext accepts no parameters when you call super(). You need SignalContext to use signals not Context. So how do you create a new context from your main class using SignalContext? Remember super() accepts no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

mxml tags are just shorthand for actionscript classes.  So I'd imagine you could start by taking a look at the auto-generated actionscript code.  There is a flash builder compiler option that will let you see this.  Using that as a template, you probably can't go too far wrong.